# HTML time and date types

Tags: html

I am using `type="time"` for my input. Is there a way to set up steps for minutes (00,15,30,45).

Also i have one input with `type="date"`. Is there a way to limit selection date, that uses cant't select some future dates.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the min and max attribute of input for limit date selection (currently only supported in opera and chrome).

I´m not sure about the steps for time selection.

Have a look at jQuery [datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)
and [timepicker](http://milesich.com/timepicker/). It works in most browsers and should satisfy your needs.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, by HTML5 drafts, you can use the `step` attribute to set the step size. For `input type=time`, its value is interpreted in seconds, so for 15 minutes, you would use

```
<input type=time step=900>
```

This is currently supported by Opera and Safari, but not Chrome (odd, because some earlier version had support, at least according to my book (literally)).

Similarly, you can set an upper limit for date using the `max` attribute. There is, however, no concept of “now” in HTML5. You would need to determine the current date when generating the page server-side, or set it client-side with JavaScript (these involve two different interpretations for “current”). Example:

```
<input type=date max="2012-08-29">
```

Works on Chrome, Opera, Safari.